# Firefox Dev: Console not showing Javascript Uncaught TypeErrors

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm not quite sure why this is happening, i have googled long but not found any similar case to mine.

I'm using FF Dev Edition (42.0a2) under Arch Linux for development, but my FF Console won't show any `Uncaught TypeErros` produced by my javascript code. Every other console.log, error message or warning is shown, except for Uncaught TypeErrors. I really don't know why this is happening. Chrome Dev Console works like expected and shows all errors, but i prefer FF Dev Console and would like to stay with it.

I've also tested to disable all plugins i use (which are few) and even a private browsing session.

Could this be an issue with our frontend, because we're using a huge ext.js frontend for our application? Or is the arch ff package broken?

Any ideas on this?

EDIT: I have now upgraded to the new version 43.0a2. same issue... eventually I will open a bug ticket for this at mozilla or ask the maintainer of the arch package. But if no one else can confirm this behaviour i am really confused...

Comment: I have the same problem. Wasted 2 hours. If you open a ticket, please post the link here so I can join in.

Comment: I'm sorry but in my case it was a bug in our software. Some idiot hijacked the console object and returned the wrong boolean which stopped the log output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have all the options checked in your js settings?

[image]

Comment: yes, I am shure. As I posted, all other logs, warnings, errors are displayed. Except for Uncaught TypeErrors. Maybe there is more that is not displayed but I had several times where typeErrors were not shown.